# Часовой пояс php перевод времени

Tags: php

На сайте вывожу время публикации 16:12, как определить часовой пояс пользователя, который зашел и время конвертировать под его, например зашел человек из лондона и время подогнало под его?

Comment: Только определять его местонахождение по IP, что не очень надёжно. Или выводить время в gmt и обновлять скриптом в браузере. Там можно получить локальное время.